# Error while accessing members of class in main function

Tags: c++, class

What is the error in this code?

I tried this code in Visual Studio, and I'm facing an error while running this code. Visual Studio is showing the error on line 29.

Point out the error and also explain it, please.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {

    int width;
    int height;

public:
    Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    void setDimensions(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    int calculateArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
};

int main() {
    Rectangle myRectangle(3, 4);

    cout << "Initial Area: " << myRectangle.calculateArea() << endl;
    myRectangle.width = 5; 

    cout << "Updated Area: " << myRectangle.calculateArea() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Compilation error? Linker error? Logic error? Please edit your question en provide the exact error. I'm guessing `myRectangle.width = 5;` gives a compiler error because class members are `private` by default.

Comment: Which line is line 29? Can you [edit] the question and mark the line with a comment? What error do you get? Please check [ask].

Comment: Any useful compiler would have given you an error message. At StackOverflow its essential to post the exact text of the error message with your question. Without the error message the question will not likely help future readers and thus not serve its #1 purpose. Also as a programmer at first error messages may be difficult to read and understand however you will need to learn to do so to be successful. Sometimes you can Google the error message to get a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code is that the **width** and **height** member variables of the `Rectangle` class are **private**. Therefore, they cannot be accessed directly from outside the class.

In the `main()` function, the line `rectangle.width = 5;` tries to access the `width` member variable of the `rectangle` object, which is not allowed and causes a compile-time error.

To fix this error, you can add a **public** member function to the `Rectangle` class that allows you to set the `width` and `height` member variables. For example, you can add the following function to the `Rectangle` class:

```cpp
void set_dimensions(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

Then, you can use this function to set the `width` and `height` of the `rectangle` object in the `main()` function, like this:

```cpp
myRectangle.setDimensions(5, 6);
```

This will set the `width` of the `rectangle` object to `5` and the `height` to `6`, and the program will run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

.width is private member of class. It cannot be accesed from outside of the class. You should use setDimensions() to change it.

Since your class hasn't any members that depend on width, nothing will break if you make it public.

If for example you wish to keep area as a class member to avoid calculating it every time the area is requested, then you must keep width private because any change of width will invalidate precalculated value of area. In this case keep it private and add special methods for class: one to get width wtithout right to change it and one that allows to set width and updates area with each change. (You only have second method in form of setDimensions())

On unrelated note:

1. Dimentions of rectangle cannot be negative so store them as unsigned value
2. calculateArea() with high probability will encounter integer overflow. Consider using long long as a return value (which is usualy stored in 8 bytes instead of 4 bytes for int).

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is on the line myRectangle.width = 5;. In the main function, you are trying to access the width member variable directly, but it is declared as private within the Rectangle class. Direct access to private members from outside the class is not allowed.

To fix this, you should use the public member function setDimensions to update the dimensions of the rectangle.